# Creating a Function depending on user input

Tags: c, function

My program is allowing the user to **enter up to 10  integers/characters into a text file**. I am then using:

```
            number = atoi(word);
            printf("\nstring  is \t %s\n", word);
            printf("integer is \t %d\n", number);
```

to convert the entered char/int from ASCII to integer.

Example :

Input: `e` Output:  `String is e, integer is 0`

Input: `10`  Output: `String is 10, integer is 10`

*I want a **function** to display the minimum integer from all of the user's inputs*. I have tested the code below to give me the smallest integer however this is **not contained within a function.** I am unable to create a function that takes into consideration a different number of user inputs each time.

The following code runs successfully to return my smallest integer:

```
    int minIndex = 0;
    int minNumber = INT_MAX;

    if (number <= minNumber)
    {
        minNumber = number;
        minIndedx = i;
    }
if (minIndex > 0)

    printf("min number is %d at position %d\n", minNumber, minIndex);
else
    printf("no numbers read in; hence: no minimum calculated.");`
```

1. **How can I call this code above from a function?**
2. *Do I need to store all the integers in an array and use a pointer to point to the value inside my array?*

Any ideas on how to proceed ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you have to do is put the code in a function and then call that function .

```
int minIndex = 0;           //Making Them Global Variables
int minNumber = INT_MAX;    //Making Them Global Variables
int i =  0;                 //Declaring And Initializing The Global 
                            //Variable i to keep count of the position.


number = atoi(word);
printf("\nstring  is \t %s\n", word);
printf("integer is \t %d\n", number);
min(number);  //Calling function min and passing it value of number


void min(int number){

    if (number <= minNumber){

         minNumber = number;
         minIndedx = i;
      }

    if (minIndex > 0)
    printf("min number is %d at position %d\n", minNumber, minIndex);

    else
    printf("no numbers read in; hence: no minimum calculated.");

    i++; //Every time Incrementing i to update position.
 }
```

Run the program in loop , and then every time you call the function min with a different user input that is stored in variable `number` , the function if the number passed to it is smaller than the set minimum , it updates the value of the minimum number , so that is how you get the minimum number of the user's input.

**NOTE :** This is not a valid program and you have to embed it in your code and change it to suit your need. I cannot make it as i do not know how are you taking input.

Comment: Please format this code properly. Also, where is the value of `i` coming from in your code?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage is this ok?

Comment: @Olaf I know i just made it to tell OP how to do it ?

Comment: @Olaf I was editing it to add that note , please read that kindly.

Comment: Thanks for your insight and imput. I will see how to implement this in my code. Also I am storing the characters in `char word[10]` and using `scanf("%s", word);`

Comment: @Ryan PLease upvote and select as best , if it has solved your query.

Comment: I will do so once i get 15 reputation marks do not worry. I will select as answer as soon as I manage to implement.. don't worry your help did not go unnoticed.

Comment: @Ryan Also there is a book , C programming a modern approach second edition , that book is a gem , please consider reading it , it is bit costly , you can get an old copy and  there are other means too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134003/discussion-on-answer-by-suraj-jain-creating-a-function-depending-on-user-input).